# Using Perl ,How to define a secondary horizontal axis in an excel sheet

Tags: excel, perl

I want to create secondary horizontal/vertical axis through perl in excel sheet.
I have searched in **Spreadsheet**::**WriteExcel**::**Chart** but could not find information related to that.
Could any one kindly help me in getting the information?
I have created primary axis with this statement.

```
$chart1->set_x_axis( name => ' Time of Day' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$chart->set_y_axis( name => 'Sample weight (kg)' );
```

From [the documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel/Chart.pm#set_y_axis()).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The statement that you have provided is for setting y axis. If I want to set another y axis( secondary) in the same chart, how do we do that?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's supported in that library.  It may be helpful if you show an image of what your goal chart is as part of your question.